# Grails parameter passing

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

Basically I am using the code below for debugging. It renders null and I cannot figure out the
reason. And by the way the else statement will always be executed at this point. At first I 
didnt have the save method but I then thought it might fix my issue. May is have to do with
the scope of my domains? As of now I have them set to session scope:
class Info {
    static scope = "session"
    String name
    String smokingStatus
    String[] symptom
    static constraints = {
    }
}

---

```
        else{//query did not find patient with that id
            def patInfo = new Info()
            patInfo.name = "Dennis"
            patInfo.smokingStatus = "Former Smoker"
            patInfo.symptom = ["Cough"]
            patInfo.save()
            redirect(action:"display", params: [patInfo:patInfo])
            //redirect(action:"login")
            //return to login action and 
        }
    }   
}

def display(){
    render params.name 
}
```

Thanks for any help its much appreciated.

Comment: Could you post some of the surrounding code for context? This isn't that valuable alone.

Comment: hi Dennis, you tell us that the "else" statement always executes, but we don't see the condition statement. How can we figure out?

Answer (score 1):

You are assign the value of patInfo to variable name patInfo so in the display action you must use:

```
render params.patInfo
```

By example if you will use the following:

```
redirect(action:"display", params: [duck:patInfo])
```

You must use:

```
render params.duck
```